# accessing static members using boost lambda

Tags: c++, stl, static-members, boost-lambda

I am trying to write some simple predicate using `boost::lambda` and I am getting tons of errors.

I checked the documentation and I have some doubt on accessing the static variable `std::string::npos` in a lambda expression. Below my code.

```
    #include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
    #include <boost/lambda/core.hpp>
    #include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv ){
        typedef std::vector< std::string > array;
        namespace bl = boost::lambda;

        size_t ( std::string::* fp )( const std::string&, size_t ) const  
                  = &std::string::find;

        std::string to_find( "AA" );
        size_t pos = 0;

        const char* data [] = { "AAAA","BBBB","","CCAACC","DDDDD" };
        array v( data, data +4 );
        assert( v.size() == 4 );
        std::replace_if(
                v.begin()
                ,v.end()
                , bl::bind( 
                             fp
                             , bl::_1
                             , bl::constant_ref( to_find ) 
                             , bl::var( pos ) 
                     ) != bl::bind( &std::string::npos, bl::_1 )
                , "||"
        );  
        return 0;
}
```

If I change the comparison

```
        != bl::bind( &std::string::npos, bl::_1 )
        to 
        != std::string::npos
```

it builds fine, but I am not sure if the expression is well formed. Sometimes I found that, because of lazy evaluation in lambda, I didn't get the expected result ( not in this case but in previous test with lambda ) because the call might be delayed.

Do you know  in general what would be the right way to access a static member in boost lambda?

I thank you all

AFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a static variable can be done using simply one of the following

```
 boost::constant( std::string::npos )
 boost::var( std::string::npos )
```

Depending on the input parameter signature also `boost::constant_ref`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::npos` is a *static* member. It doesn't vary based on which string instance you're using. Your change to use `!= std::string::npos` is correct.

Using `boost::constant` or `boost::var` allows you to delay evaluation of the static member's value. Without any modifiers, its value will be evaluated once, at the time the `replace_if` parameters are evaluated (the same time as `v.begin()` and `v.end()`). If you need to delay evaluation until the point where the bound expression is executed (inside of `replace_if`), then use `boost::constant` or `boost::var`, and if the static member's value changes over the course of the function, those changes will be visible inside the bound expression.